# Could I ignore max column 16384 when reading an xlsx file

Tags: excel, openxml

everyone here:

Sometime, after I copy a sheet from book A (Excel 2007) to book B (Excel 2010) in Excel, the copied sheet in book B become one columns more with max=16384:

see the 3rd line of the codes below:

```
<x:cols xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <x:col min="1" max="1" width="16.375" style="86" bestFit="1" customWidth="1" />
  <x:col min="2" max="16384" width="9" style="86" />
</x:cols>
```

But actually, column 2 ~ 16384 are empty cells with nothing changed.

Does anyone know why does excel create this extra column?

Could I just ignore this record when I read the file? I hope someone can tell me that this record is just a redundant record created by normal copying operation...so that I can ignore it. Because In my case, I don't want to really create 16384 columns.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, you can ignore that column 2 to 16384 entry. Assuming you already know those columns are empty.

The long answer (*of course* there's one...) is you need to create that entry in the new worksheet if you still want to preserve the width=9 and style=86 properties. Judging from the data, I'm assuming you did a select all in the worksheet (Ctrl-A probably), resized the width to 9, set a particular style (I don't know what the style is, but the 0-based index is 86 in your stylesheet XML file), and then resized only the 1st column to 16.375.

Let's say the 86th style is a background colour of light blue, text is centre-aligned and bolded. If you didn't copy that entry, your new worksheet won't have those styles applied to columns 2 to 16384. So while those columns in the new worksheet is empty, when your users (or whoever will continue using that resulting Excel file) enter data in the new worksheet, it will look like someone who's fashion clueless did it (no style at all. :) Sorry, couldn't help it...)